# How to do a full screen in lwjgl?

Tags: java, fullscreen, lwjgl

When I do the following code I do achieve a full screen but it is not decorated, meaning that it does not have the banner at the top with the exit and minimize button.
Also, after getting the task manager to close it down, the program changes my screen resolution to 800, 600 so I have to change it back myself.
Can you tell me what to change about the following code?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    AppGameContainer appgc;
    try{
        appgc = new AppGameContainer(new Game(gamename));
        appgc.setDisplayMode(800, 600, true);
        appgc.setFullscreen(true);
        appgc.start();

    }catch(SlickException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: You are explicitly setting resolution to 800x600 in appgc.setDisplayMode(800, 600, true); so it is changing resolution to 800x600

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the exit button and the rest of the window banner up?

Comment: I think you should go through API or docs like that. In office I couldn't open docs of lwjgl, so couldn't find more info for you

Comment: **[This](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=LWJGL_Basics_5_(Fullscreen))** page explains it all.

Comment: I forgot to add that I am also using Slick along side lwjgl.

Comment: Do how do I get the banner?

Comment: If you need the title bar, then you cannot go full screen or change the screen resolution. Better maximize the JFrame holding the application using `jframe.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)`